# How to add an Array or json type column in laravel migration table?

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I want to add a column which is an array or json type by the default it should be an empty if i am not passing any value ,and it should take a value (if i pass any value it should take a value otherwise it should take empty/null value automatically).How to acheive this thing ...?

```
 $table->json('collabMail',['null','sai'])->default(null);
```

i am writing like this but it's not working

i am trying one more way like this `$table->json('collabMail')->default(null)->change();` it's migrating the table but collabMail column is not reflected in my database

Answer (score 1):

You can make it nullable() and also don't forget to cast in your model

```
protected $casts = ['collabMail' => 'array'];
```